# How "unique" human vagina is?

Tags: human-biology, anatomy, mammals

Regading penis [Dixson](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Z9N_BokMAMkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) showed that it is not really unique and complex. This argument (and there were some others) was used against the idea of human polygynandry.

But what about vaginal shape? I know it is wider as deeper it goes and cervix is convex shaped, which could  give an advantage for storing semen. However, I am actually wondering if other primates have similar vaginal shapes (because it can shed light on the question of mating system). Are there any studies on the topic?

Comment: Check the wiki page for clitoris and some mammalian orgasm research... ostriches have a clitoris and other species such as spider monkeys and spotted hyenas have clitorises as long as their male counterparts, so we are different form spider monkeys.

Comment: @com.prehensible Well, I know, say, that bonobos have 3x larger clitores (given they are smaller). But I am asking about unique features of human vaginas, not primates'. I am pretty sure there are primates with clitores comparable in relative size with human ones.

Comment: This page talks about labia http://aquatic-human-ancestor.org/anatomy/sexual-features.html